# Getting a post using Facebook4J

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get a post from Facebook using the Facebook4J API. It's been working excellently, so far, but I've run into a little problem.

When I use

```
PostMethods pp = null;
Post post = pp.getPost(postId);
```

I see problems. If the post ID is something like "592496714151070", this call works absolutely fine, but if I give a post Id like "164204816980264_592496714151070", I get a runtime exception:

```
RuntimeException in run(): [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1d944379
```

The second type of post Id is for a post that is on the wall of a page, so it's the pageId followed by a post Id.

Is there way to fix this, or saving that, a way to get posts from 'others' on a facebook page's wall?

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question completely. However, you don't have to access all posts explicitly. You can crawl them altogether using a simple generic facebook4j client as described here: 
[Getting posts from a page using Facebook4j api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125895/getting-posts-from-a-page-using-facebook4j-api/20774476#20774476)